# New custom action in MSP

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I'm trying to add custom action to the MSP, which didn't exist in the original MSI.
Does somebody knows how to do it?

Thanks,
Ievgen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .msp patch file is the delta between the original MSI file and the new MSI file. So you just build your new MSI file with the custom action in it and you'll end up with a patch that includes it.